# Getting data from multiple forms using one submit button

Tags: html, forms, flask

I'm trying to get data on_submit from input fields in multiple form fields.  But I want to use one submit button from one of the fields.  is this even possible?

```
class Form1(FlaskForm):
    entry1 = StringField(('Entry 1'))

class Form2(FlaskForm):
    entry2 = StringField(('Entry 2'))
    submit = SubmitField(('Register'))


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form1= Form1()
    form2= Form2()
    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        entry1 = request.form.get('entry1')
        entry2= request.form.get('entry2')
        flash((entry1))
        flash((entry2))
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form1=form1, form2=form2)


{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form1)}}
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form2) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the Submit button to a new class that inherits the other forms. From what I understand, `validate_on_submit()` processes and validates the fields of the called form, which includes any fields of inherited form classes.

```
class Form1(FlaskForm):
    entry1 = StringField(('Entry 1'))

class Form2(FlaskForm):
    entry2 = StringField(('Entry 2'))

class FinalForm(Form1, Form2):
    submit = SubmitField(('Register'))
```

Now you only have to refer to the final form in the call and rendering.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = FinalForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        entry1 = request.form.get('entry1')
        entry2 = request.form.get('entry2')
        flash((entry1))
        flash((entry2))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Here were the basic html templates I tested with success, trying to keep with the format you showed.

base.html :

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        {% block app_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
        </div>
    </div> 

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've actually moved on and consolidated all my classes into one form.  But to your response, I did attempt something like this but was still unable to get data back from forms other than the one that contained the submit button.  Did you test your example?

Comment: Yes. The fields generate on the page and the inputs for both are returned in flash messages on submit. I can edit to include my template code as well. I assumed your snippet was excluding the code that actually displayed the flash messages, right?

Comment: Ah cool.  Even though I found a work around I'll try out your solution on the side for future considerations.  And yes I did exclude the base.html that held the flash messaging functionality.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understand your problem correctly, but you can use WTForms to build your forms. You'd have to define another class though that holds the both classes with the fields you need to submit.

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: What exactly are you not understanding?  Maybe I can clarify it better.  I've attempted to encapsulate my classes into a FieldForm class but that didn't help me getting data back from both forms on submit.